# What is the best way to sync data (binary and text) from a handheld device to server

Tags: iphone, web-services, synchronization

For example, I have a blackberry or iphone, some applications on it generated some binary and text information, I want to sync those data back to my home web server with fixed IP. What is the best way?

web service, can I use HTTP post or put to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to find a way to version the data that is being shared.

Otherwise this sounds like a very similar question to this:
[Vote for the best protocol for the given scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477925/vote-for-the-best-protocol-for-the-given-scenario/1480615#1480615)

Comment: @steven, thanks for the help. I think my question is pretty much the same as the question you mentioned. BTW, Can I close my questions?

Comment: yes, the person who asks the question determines if the solutions were correct or not.